# Watermark on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, watermark

I want to add a image as a watermark on my website. I have prepared a master page and I want to include it on the master page it self so it can be implemented in entire website.

I want to put in such a way that while scrolling the image should stay steady while the content is moving with the scroll.

What I did basically 
in my css

```
.Watermark
{
    position:   absolute;
    left:       expression(this.offsetParent.scrollLeft + 180);
    top:        expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop + 320);
    z-index:    99;
}
```

and in master page's content holder

```
<img src="./images/watermark.gif" mce_src="./images/watermark.gif" class="Watermark" style="opacity:0.2;filter:alpha(opacity=20);">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `position: fixed`

Comment: Arrangement of the image tag is proper?